# Сортировка данных через Интерфейс Comparator

Tags: java, сортировка, java-stream, compare

Нужна помощь в сортировке через Интерфейс Comparator или Stream.

Задача , нужно отсортировать значения Map по убыванию.Найти наименьшее значение и вернуть его ключ, сохранив в переменную, если элементов с наименьшим значением несколько взять первый. Люди в интернете советуют использовать Comparator или Stream.sorted(), но я новичок в java , и не могу понять как это реализовать .

Любая помощь приветствуется, если можно на примере .

Есть такой код, с тестовыми данными:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> managers = new ArrayList<>();

Map<String,Object> user1 = new HashMap<>(),user2 = new HashMap<>(),user3 = new HashMap<>(),user4 = new HashMap<>();

user1.put("id","777");
user1.put("name","user1");

user2.put("id","888");
user2.put("name","user2");

user3.put("id","999");
user3.put("name","user3");

user4.put("id","1000");
user4.put("name","user4");

//Достаю из листа , ид всех пользователей.
List listId = managers.stream().map(m->m.get("id")).collect(Collectors.toList());

// в задаче, уже есть данные которые надо отсортировать, лежат они в Map answer
// имеют вид {777=0104, 888=0102, 999=0103, 1000=0102}
Map<String,String> answer = new HashMap<>();

//Пробовал так не получилось: зато вывожу в лог , объекты которые хочу сравнить.
//Думаю перед сравнением , строку надо преобразовать в int , Integer.parseInt(answer.get(a))

listId.sort((a,b)-> {
   System.out.println("answer.get(a) " + answer.get(a));
   System.out.println("answer.get(b) " + answer.get(b));
      return answer.get(a).compareTo(answer.get(b));//Здесь наверное нужен Comparator
});

//Дальше сам компаратор
Collections.sort(listId,new Comparator<String>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
      int r;
      Integer n1 = Integer.parseInt(answer.get(o1));
      Integer n2 = Integer.parseInt(answer.get(o2));
      //Здесь сравнить значения?

      return r;
   }
});
 //или как можно написать через 
  listId.stream().sorted();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если задача сводится к поиску минимального элемента в списке по какому-либо параметру, то сортировка этого списка может быть излишней, что в целом приведёт к повышению вычислительной сложности, так как поиск минимума имеет линейную сложность O(N), а быстрая сортировка в среднем O(N log N).

Также следует отметить, что вместо использования `Map<String, Object>` для хранения данных о пользователях правильнее было бы создать некий простой класс (POJO) или же кортеж (record) в Java 16 и выше.  В частности, так будет проще найти полную информацию о первом пользователе, для id которого зафиксировано минимальное значение в мапе `answers`.

Для этого следует воспользоваться поиском минимума в стриме `Stream::min`, в который следовало бы передать компаратор.  Поскольку `Stream::min` возвращает `Optional<T>`, в данном случае для непустого входного списка можно применить `Optional.get`

```java
record User(String id, String name) {}

List<User> managers = Arrays.asList(
    new User("777", "user1"), new User( "888", "user2"),
    new User("999", "user3"), new User("1000", "user4")
);

Map<String, String> answers = Map.of(
   "777", "0104",    "888", "0102",   "999", "0103",   "1000", "0102"
);

User firstMin = managers.stream()
        .min(Comparator.comparingInt(
            u -> Integer.parseInt(answers.get(u.id()))
        )) // Optional<User>
        .get();
System.out.println(firstMin); // -> User[id=888, name=user2]
```

Если существует вероятность, что в списке `managers` окажется элемент, для которого не будет соответствия в мапе `answers`, для обращения к элементам мапы можно использовать `Map::getOrDefault`, возвращающее слишком большое значение, например, *строковое* представление `Integer.MAX_VALUE`:

```java
List<User> managers2 = Arrays.asList(
    new User("777", "user1"), new User( "888", "user2"),
    new User("999", "user3"), new User("2000", "user5")
);

User firstMin2 = managers2.stream()
        .min(Comparator.comparingInt(
            u -> Integer.parseInt(answers.getOrDefault(
                u.id(), String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            ))
        ))
        .get();
```

В случае пустого входного списка минимальный элемент не будет обнаружен, и тогда`Optional::get` выбросит исключение `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present`.

Comment: ,ваш ответ был ценным для меня , в целом ваш вариант мне нравится больше, но так как микро задача заключалась , в том чтоб при определенных условиях, отсортировать данные, я не стал прибегать к написанию вспомогательного класса, так же вы правы насчёт сравнения Integer.compare(n1, n2).

Свой вариант оставлю ниже, он очень похож на ваш_)
Спасибо за помощь и удачи!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> answer = new HashMap<>();
        answer.put("777", "0104");
        answer.put("888", "0102");
        answer.put("999", "0103");
        answer.put("1000", "0102");

        Map.Entry<String,String> res = answer.entrySet().stream().min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue((o1, o2) -> {
            int n1 = Integer.parseInt(o1);
            int n2 = Integer.parseInt(o2);
            return n1 - n2;
        })).orElse(null);

        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

```
888=0102
```

Comment: Спасибо , то что было, нужно , а можете пожалуйста объяснить принцип самого сравнения,  return n1 - n2; 
как мы их сравниваем ? почему нет операции сравнения типа ? a < b , b>a, 
и как получаем именно первый элемент из мапы answer с наименьшим значением?

Comment: В `n1 - n2` три возможных результата: положительный (n1>n2), отрицательный (n1<n2) и ноль (n1==n2). [Здесь подробно](https://javarush.com/groups/posts/1939-comparator-v-java) . Меньший, потому что используем метод `min()`

Comment: Просто и понятно, 

Comment: вместо `n1 - n2` в общем случае следует использовать `Integer.compare(n1, n2)`

Answer (score 0):

мой вариант решения задачи , благодаря подсказкам:

```
 List<Map<String,Object>> managers2 = Arrays.asList(
  ImmutableMap.of(
     "id","777",
     "name","user1"
  ),
  ImmutableMap.of(
     "id","888",
     "name","user2"
  ),
  ImmutableMap.of(
     "id","999",
     "name","user3"
  ),
  ImmutableMap.of(
     "id","1000",
     "name","user4"
  )
);

Map<String, String> answers = ImmutableMap.of(
  "777", "0104",    "888", "0102",   "999", "0103",   "1000", "0102"
);
List<Map<String,Object>> sortedTest = managers2.stream().sorted(
  (first, second) -> {
     int n1 = Integer.parseInt(answers.getOrDefault(first.get("id"),"9999"));
     int n2 = Integer.parseInt(answers.getOrDefault(second.get("id"),"9999"));
     return Integer.compare(n1, n2);
  }
).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println("Отсортированные данные: " + sortedTest);
System.out.println("Первый элемент с наименьшим значением: " + sortedTest.remove(0));
System.out.println("Остальные элементы: " + sortedTest);
```